# Tangents are drawn from the point $P(-2,6)$ to the parabola $y^2=8x$ and meet it at A and B. Find locus of centre of circle with AB as diameter

Tags: conic-sections

My problem is that A and B are clearly fixed points, so how can the centre of the circle be a locus of it centre is also fixed? Is there something wrong with the question or am I missing an Important detail?

Comment: No, if $AB$ is a diameter, the center of the circle is always the midpoint of $AB$. If $AB$ is instead a chord (random guess), the locus would be the perpendicular bisector of $AB$.

Comment: It is hard to come up with a convincingly correct answer to a poorly worded problem. If $A,B$ were not meant to be the endpoints of the diameter, the locus of center would be the line through $A,B$.